# Is the following relation correct?

Tags: homology-cohomology, tensor-products, torsion-groups

Using Kunneth theorem I would like to compute the following 4th homology:

$
H_4(S^2\times S^3/\mathbb{Z}_k,\mathbb{Z})\simeq H_4(S^2,\mathbb{Z})\otimes H_0(S^3/\mathbb{Z}_k,\mathbb{Z})\oplus H_3(S^2,\mathbb{Z})\otimes H_1(S^3/\mathbb{Z}_k,\mathbb{Z})\oplus H_2(S^2,\mathbb{Z})\otimes H_2(S^3/\mathbb{Z}_k,\mathbb{Z})\oplus H_1(S^2,\mathbb{Z})\otimes H_3(S^3/\mathbb{Z}_k,\mathbb{Z})\oplus H_0(S^2,\mathbb{Z})\otimes H_4(S^3/\mathbb{Z}_k,\mathbb{Z}) \simeq 0\otimes \mathbb{Z} \oplus 0 \otimes \mathbb{Z}_k \oplus \mathbb{Z}\otimes 0\oplus 0 \otimes \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}\otimes 0 \simeq 0
$

Is it true that $0\otimes \mathbb{Z}\simeq 0$? I was thinking in terms of tensor products of matrices, but maybe I'm confused. What confuses me is that if I use the Poincaré duality and the universal coefficient theorem, it should be $\mathbb{Z}$. I mean

$ H_4(S^2\times S^3/\mathbb{Z}_k,\mathbb{Z})\simeq H^1(S^2\times S^3/\mathbb{Z}_k,\mathbb{Z})$

by Poincaré duality in 5d. While in general it should be true that

$H^q(X_D,\mathbb{Z})\simeq H_q^{\text{free}}(X_D,\mathbb{Z})\oplus \text{Tor}H_{q-1}(X_D,\mathbb{Z})$

Computing the first homology of my space:

$H_1(S^2\times S^3/\mathbb{Z}_k,\mathbb{Z})\simeq H_1(S^2,\mathbb{Z})\otimes H_0(S^3/\mathbb{Z}_k,\mathbb{Z})\oplus H_0(S^2,\mathbb{Z})\otimes H_1(S^3/\mathbb{Z}_k,\mathbb{Z})\simeq 0\otimes \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}\otimes \mathbb{Z}_k\simeq \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_k$

so first of all I think that I don't understand the $\oplus$ neither, but I don't see my mistake. The first homology should be correct because I know it also for other reason, but then, the free part of $H_1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ so the 4th homology should be $\mathbb{Z}$. Where am I mistaking?

Comment: When there is torsion in homology, the Künneth theorem should also have a Tor term. That should fix your computation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is true. Whenever you have a ring $R$ and a $R$-module $M$, then $M \otimes_R R \cong M$ or more generally $M/IM \cong M \otimes_R R/I$ for any ideal $I \subset R$. You can also see $0 \otimes_R M \cong 0$ directly as every elementary tensor is $0$. That is because $$0 \otimes m = (0+0) \otimes m = 0 \otimes m + 0 \otimes m,$$ such that we get $0 \otimes m = 0$ by subtracting $0 \otimes m$ from both sides.

Edit: I did not check your computation btw.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind to check my computation also? It seems weird to me that using Kunneth theorem I get 0, while if I use the fact that H_4 in 5d is Poincaré dual to H^1, and then using the universal coefficient theorem I should be able to relate H^1 to the free part of the 1st homology of my space (which should be ZZ) and the torsion part of the 0th homology of my space (which should be 0). So using this other method I get that H_4 is ZZ and not 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm writing down the computation now.